# cannot run ionic on ios, error comes from cordova itself

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

cannot run ionic on ios, error comes from cordova itself where default target is undefined.

```
ionic cordova run ios --debug
```

gives error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at /Users/user/project//platforms/ios/cordova/lib/build.js:162:60
    at _fulfilled (/Users/user/project//node_modules/q/q.js:854:54)
    at /Users/user/project//node_modules/q/q.js:883:30
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/Users/user/project//node_modules/q/q.js:816:13)
    at /Users/user/project//node_modules/q/q.js:624:44
    at runSingle (/Users/user/project//node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
    at flush (/Users/user/project//node_modules/q/q.js:125:13)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you paste the code that is throwing the error, rather than the screenshot ? And also the location of the file.

The seems to be a file generated during the build process. If that's the case, the actual error might be in the code & not cordova.

Answer (score -1):

Please update your iOS cordova platform to v5 like:

```
ionic cordova platform rm ios
```

then

```
ionic cordova platform add ios@5
```

Don't forget to update the resources, as you might find some "Cordova bot" images in your resources under "Xcode assets".

Comment: I'm using cordova iOS v 5.1.1

Comment: Have you try this command `cordova run ios --buildFlag=-UseModernBuildSystem=0` ?